# Writing to a System File Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, macos

I'm working with an API with a feature that can only be accessed (easily) using Javascript, but I want to use the API to save a .txt file to my server. Is there any way to achieve this on a Mac OSX machine? I know that JS running in a browser is prohibited from doing this, so I guess this is really a two part question: (1) what's the simplest way to run a 10 line JS script on Mac OSX and (2) how would I write data to a txt file doing this?

Comment: Node or Rhino? It's unclear what you're doing, though.

Comment: I'm not really looking to do any full fledged server side scripting with node or rhino. Literally, all I need to do is use JS to access the Spotify API, grab some data about the albums I'm listening to, store it in a txt file, and then run the rest of my program using Python.

Comment: Why can't you just access the API from Python then?

Comment: If you want to run JavaScript on the server, you need to use a JavaScript on the server. That essentially boils down to Node or Rhino. You can access the API from essentially any scripting language, but I don't see a real difference between using, say, Python or Ruby compared to JS.

Comment: Google "python spotify api" and you'll find a number of libraries for accessing Spotify directly from Python.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately none of them provide an easy way for accessing a list of all of the album's in a user's library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for a `headless browser` for example [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). I haven't used it, but it should run JS well.

The same restrictions apply though, no filesystem access from JS.
Unless you use something like the plugin framework in FF, in that case you have elevated rights for the scripts.

Besides that you could create a wrapper in php, perl or other language, and pass on the data from JS to them in an ajax call, and they write the txt for you.